# For which values of $a$, equation $\sqrt{x-3}+ax=2a+3$ has one solution for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For which values of $a$, euation $\sqrt{x-3}+ax=2a+3$ has one solution for $x$?

According to my student solution book, the answer is $a\in \left \{ \frac{3-\sqrt{10}}{2} \right \}\cup \left [ 0;3 \right ]$ but I cannot figure out how they did it. And I'm more interested in *how* to arrive at the correct answer than I am in the answer itself.

Comment: Solve the equation with respect to $a$, i.e. get $a=f(x)$, and then draw the graph of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

take the square to get
$x-3=(2a+3)^2+a^2x^2-2ax(2a+3)$

which becomes

$a^2x^2-( 2a(2a+3)+1)x+(2a+3)^2+3=0$

it has one solution if the discriminant is zero.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{x-3}$ is defined in $\Bbb R$ only when $x\ge 3$ and the corresponding value of $a$ for $x=3$ is $3$. For other values of $x$, making the equality gives for $x=3+\delta\gt 3$ 
$$a=\frac{3}{x-2}=\frac{3}{1+\delta}\Rightarrow a\lt3$$

On the other hand $a$ can not be negative (in this context!) and tends to $0$ when $\delta \to \infty$ hence the values of $a$ form the closed interval $[0,3]$.

However there are negative values of $a$, other than $\frac{3-\sqrt{10}}{2}$, for which one has equality, for example $a\approx-0.05$ which with $x\approx 17.1$ gives the equality (*obviously equivalent to the given one*)
$$\sqrt{x-3}-3=a(2-x)\\\sqrt{17.1-3}-3\approx -0.05(2-17.1)\approx 0.755$$

Notice that $\frac{3-\sqrt{10}}{2}\approx-0.081\lt -0.05$ and we can ensure that for other negative values of $a$ one has equality also. In the figure below it is show the intersection point of curves $\sqrt{x-3}-3$ and $a(2-x)$ for $a=-0.07$. There is a little interval of negative numbers to add to the interval $[0,3]$ and not only the negative point $\frac{3-\sqrt{10}}{2}$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set $\sqrt{x-3}=t$, so $x=t^2+3$ and the equation becomes
$$
t+at^2+3a=2a+3 \tag{*}
$$
or
$$
at^2+t+a-3=0
$$
This equation should have a single nonnegative solution. The case $a=0$ gives $t=3$, hence $x=12$; so we can assume $a\ne0$. First of all it must have one, so the discriminant should be nonnegative:
$$
1-4a^2+12a\ge0
$$
so $4a^2-12a-1\le0$, which holds for
$$
\frac{3-\sqrt{10}}{2}\le a\le\frac{3+\sqrt{10}}{2}
$$
Now we can distinguish a few cases based on [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs)

### Case $a=(3+\sqrt{10})/2$

Equation (*) has a double negative solution.

### Case $3<a<(3+\sqrt{10})/2$

Equation (*) has two distinct negative solutions.

### Case $a=3$

Equation (*) has a negative solution and a null solution

### Case $0<a<3$

Equation (*) has one negative and one positive solution

### Case $a=0$

Equation (*) has a single positive solution, as already seen.

### Case $(3-\sqrt{10})/2<a<0$

Equation (*) has two positive solutions

### Case $a=(3-\sqrt{10})/2$

Equation (*) has a double positive solution

### Summary

The cases where our equation has a single positive solution are when (*) has a unique positive solution (double or not). So we find
$$
a\in\left\{\frac{3-\sqrt{10}}{2}\right\}\cup[0,3]
$$